# Period to calculate the universal gravitational constant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

To calculate the torsion constant in [Cavendish experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment) we need the period of it, so my question is if I need to measure the time the rod with two small spheres takes to do an oscillation (with an small angle), as with the simple pendulum (but rotating) or the time it took to do the experiment with the big spheres included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to measure the torsion constant by timing the oscillation before adding the two big spheres. If the big spheres are present the system is no longer a simple harmonic oscillator because the restoring force is now a complicated function of the rotation angle.

Comment: I first thought that, but in this page [http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravitation_cavendish_experiment_derivation.htm#.VZiFnvm4iW4] it says that there is a torsion coefficient at equilibrium point (referring this point as where the ball touch each other), also in the final equation is like I could vary the value for the angle while maintaining the rest constant but the G wouldn't be constant, so the period should also change depending on the angle.

Comment: @user162485: That article does imply you measure the oscillation with the large masses present, though it doesn't say so explicitly. If so it is wrong, though in practice if the oscillation is small the error will be small.